# fit a curve on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization

Assume we have 2d parametric surface 
$\textbf{p} = \textbf{p}(u_1,u_2)$ and imagine we have a particle moving on this surface drawing a curve $\textbf{c} = \textbf{c}(t)$ where $t \in [a,b]$ (or defined as a Darboux frame).
How to fit the curve on this surface, that is find a point $(u_1,u_2)$ that corresponds to the first point of the curve $t=a$? (assuming no orientation fitting is required).

PS. The goal of the question is to look for keywords/ideas rather than closed-form solutions or even algorithms.

Comment: The blunt answer is $(u_1, u_2) = \mathbf{p}^{-1}(\mathbf{c}(a))$, i.e., the invert the parametrization on its image. Since the initial point $\mathbf{c}(a)$ is arbitrary, you can't expect a better answer in general.

Comment: actually $a$ is arbitrary and I should have said $t \in [0,z]$, so we have a curve of some length floating and we want to find the *optimal* location for this curve on the surface. Sorry if my notation/description is confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can take $v_1 = t$ and $v_2 = c(t)$ to express the curve as 
$$p = p\left(\  t, c(t) \ \right)$$
for $a \leq t \leq b$. So at $t =a$, we have $$p = p\left(\ a, c(a) \  \right).$$
Does this work for you?

Comment: Why can we guarantee the pair (,c())? Why we can express the curve in that way?, I know that it's correct, but I can't explain why